# Laravel Redis Session Driver doesn't work

Tags: php, session, laravel, redis, laravel-4

I'm having difficulties using the laravel 4 "redis" session driver.
The problem is nothing gets actually stored.

Things i've checked:

- I've set the driver to `redis` in Session-config file and cache-config file
- In database-config file a database config for redis is specified:
- I tried storing something manually with the redis-class, that did work, storing with the session class did not work

  ```
  // this is in my session config
  'driver' => 'redis',

  //this is my db-config
  'redis' => array(

      'cluster' => true,

      'default' => array(
          'host'     => '127.0.0.1',
          'port'     => 6379,
          'database' => 0,
      ),

  ),


  //this works
  $redis = Redis::connection();
  $redis->set('name', 'Taylor');

  //this doesn't work
  Session::put('name', 'Taylor');
  ```

When i change the session to `native` it works

Any help would be appreciated

**UPDATE**
That's interesting:
When I use `redis-cli monitor`as suggested by @philo, I get some output while trying to log in my L4 application:

```
`1387191809.513730 [0 127.0.0.1:59268] "SELECT" "0"
1387191809.513835 [0 127.0.0.1:59268] "GET" "laravel:siau639prmckja34le11vbsfl7"
1387191809.863851 [0 127.0.0.1:59268] "SET" "laravel:siau639prmckja34le11vbsfl7" "s:226:\"_sf2_attributes|a:2:{s:6:\"_token\";s:40:\"9LPf354C2ZNtw0Oc1zyafSvMdFFlspPiJsq8w90v\";s:5:\"flash\";a:2:{s:3:\"old\";a:0:{}s:3:\"new\";a:0:{}}}_sf2_flashes|a:0:{}_sf2_meta|a:3:{s:1:\"u\";i:1387191809;s:1:\"c\";i:1387191809;s:1:\"l\";s:1:\"0\";}\";"
1387191809.866655 [0 127.0.0.1:59268] "EXPIRE" "laravel:siau639prmckja34le11vbsfl7" "0"
1387191828.464840 [0 127.0.0.1:59279] "SELECT" "0"
1387191828.464970 [0 127.0.0.1:59279] "GET" "laravel:siau639prmckja34le11vbsfl7"
1387191828.581774 [0 127.0.0.1:59279] "SET" "laravel:siau639prmckja34le11vbsfl7" "s:599:\"_sf2_attributes|a:4:{s:6:\"_token\";s:40:\"KSkc5OAsp9Psz3MC7dYo6FfkTvcdK6I6HcisSyJ3\";s:10:\"_old_input\";a:3:{s:6:\"_token\";s:40:\"9LPf354C2ZNtw0Oc1zyafSvMdFFlspPiJsq8w90v\";s:8:\"username\";s:10:\"bertcasier\";s:8:\"password\";s:4:\"test\";}s:5:\"flash\";a:2:{s:3:\"new\";a:0:{}s:3:\"old\";a:2:{i:0;s:10:\"_old_input\";i:1;s:6:\"errors\";}}s:6:\"errors\";O:29:\"Illuminate\\Support\\MessageBag\":2:{s:11:\"\x00*\x00messages\";a:1:{s:7:\"general\";a:1:{i:0;s:48:\"Ongeldige gebruikersnaam/wachtwoordcombinatie...\";}}s:9:\"\x00*\x00format\";s:8:\":message\";}}_sf2_flashes|a:0:{}_sf2_meta|a:3:{s:1:\"u\";i:1387191828;s:1:\"c\";i:1387191828;s:1:\"l\";s:1:\"0\";}\";"
1387191828.582214 [0 127.0.0.1:59279] "EXPIRE" "laravel:siau639prmckja34le11vbsfl7" "0"
1387191828.613536 [0 127.0.0.1:59284] "SELECT" "0"
1387191828.613649 [0 127.0.0.1:59284] "GET" "laravel:siau639prmckja34le11vbsfl7"
1387191828.653734 [0 127.0.0.1:59284] "SET" "laravel:siau639prmckja34le11vbsfl7" "s:226:\"_sf2_attributes|a:2:{s:6:\"_token\";s:40:\"SMxXljPLDaViVVSpCohfOKlpByhjp8E2ywS6zVkh\";s:5:\"flash\";a:2:{s:3:\"old\";a:0:{}s:3:\"new\";a:0:{}}}_sf2_flashes|a:0:{}_sf2_meta|a:3:{s:1:\"u\";i:1387191828;s:1:\"c\";i:1387191828;s:1:\"l\";s:1:\"0\";}\";"
1387191828.654102 [0 127.0.0.1:59284] "EXPIRE" "laravel:siau639prmckja34le11vbsfl7" "0"
1387191878.208814 [0 127.0.0.1:59358] "config" "get" "databases"
1387191878.215094 [0 127.0.0.1:59358] "INFO" "keyspace"
1387191880.176125 [0 127.0.0.1:59358] "select" "0"
1387191880.176314 [0 127.0.0.1:59358] "keys" "*"`
```

Seems like my session expires immediately?
I wrote a custom Auth User Provider which logs me in, in a rest-API, and stores the result in the session. But when I use the redis session driver, I get redirected immediately back to the login page. When I use RDM (redis client GUI) I can't find any session variables

Comment: Are you using Laravel 4.0 or 4.1? If you are using 4.1, try to set cluster to `false`.

Comment: I'm am using 4.0.8. I tried setting cluster on and off, but it doesn't help

Comment: Do you see any activity in the console when you run `redis-cli monitor`?

Comment: @philo I tried using your command. I can see output, so the REDIS-connection seems to work, but I'm guessing everything expires immediately? I've updated the question with the output. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've found the solution thanks to the tip from @philo.

The session lifetime in my config file was set to `zero`, because I want my session to expire on browser close. That works for native sessions, but for redis sessions it causes the session to expire immediately. When I change the life time, my session works as expected.

Now I'm still searching how to expire on browser close

Comment: hey how did you manage to set redis as session what config should I set?

Answer (score 1):

> Now I'm still searching how to expire on browser close

Note that the lifetime of the cookie and the session data are unrelated. You want the cookie lifetime to be 0 (remove on browser close) and the session data lifetime to be longer (as long as you allow between requests).

Answer (score 0):

You have to enclose your route to controller with middlewareGroups - Laravel 5.2

Route::group(['middlewareGroups' => ['web']], function () {
...
});